# How to encode 60p MP4 video to play on TVs?

Tags: video, full-hd

I have 60fps MP4 videos shot with a Canon G7x camera.  They playback find on my laptop, however I would like for the videos to be playable on TVs that have video file playback capability (such as my Samsung Smart LED TV.) I have tried converting to .MOV using QuickTime, but that format also does not work.

Is there a way to prepare such videos to allow them to play directly on TVs?

Comment: have you tried checking which codecs your TV can play (the manual should tell you) and convert to them. Or convert to video and just feed that to your TV over HDMI.

Comment: I am a newbie to this video world, I will check what's supported by my tv. For the codec conversion, do I have to use any specific software? Could you please share the names of those? Right now, I have iMovie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, smart TVs are still a relatively young market and the ability to play back video files is not yet uniform.  Each TV may support or not support a variety of formats, resolutions and frame rates.  Your best bet is likely to stick to formats used by popular services such as youtube and NetFlix as these platforms increase the likelihood that a manufacturer will support that specific format.

Alternately, if you know what model TV you are targeting, you can look at the documentation for the TV for the specific codecs and frameratest that are supported by the TV and pick one of them to match.

Comment: I checked with Samsung support and they provided me a link with supported codecs (`http://support-us.samsung.com/cyber/popup/iframe/pop_troubleshooting_fr.jsp?idx=409600&modelname=UN60ES6100F&modelcode=UN60ES6100FXZA`). It looks like for everything they support only up to 30FPS. Thats why my TV does not play 60FPS video. :(